# what is the difference between PPI, SPI and SGI interrupts?

Tags: arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In ARM architecture I have read that there are 3 kinds of interrupt :

- PPI - Per processor interrupts
- SPI - Shared processor interrupts
- SGI - Software generated interrupts

I want to know what are these, and how they are different from each other ?

Comment: The terms are actually "Private Peripheral Interrupt" and "Shared Peripheral Interrupt", and they're pretty much exactly what the names say they are - i.e. some interrupts come from peripherals that are private to each processor (e.g. local timers), some come from peripherals that are shared between processors (e.g. general system stuff like network/USB/etc.), and some can be triggered directly by software (e.g. for inter-processor signalling). Beyond that, there isn't really room to start explaining [the entire GIC spec](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0048b/index.html)...

Comment: thank you, your comment is helpful

Comment: You can also read [tag:arm+gic](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[arm]+gic) questions which have many explanation of these terms as part of other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How SMP schedule work in Linux kernel? (ARM architecture)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182160/how-smp-schedule-work-in-linux-kernel-arm-architecture)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Software Generated Interrupt (SGI)**
This interrupt is generated explicitly by software by writing to a dedicated distributor register, the Software Generated Interrupt Register. It is most commonly used for inter-core communication. SGIs can be targeted at all, or at a selected group of cores in the system. Interrupt numbers 0-15 are reserved for this. The software manages the exact interrupt number used for communication.

**Private Peripheral Interrupt (PPI)**
This interrupt is generated by a peripheral that is private to an individual core. Interrupt numbers 16-31 are reserved for this. PPIs identify interrupt sources private to the core, and are independent of the same source on another core, for example, per-core timer.

**Shared Peripheral Interrupt (SPI)**
This interrupt is generated by a peripheral that the Interrupt Controller can route to more than one core. Interrupt numbers 32-1020 are used for this. SPIs are used to signal interrupts from various peripherals accessible across the whole system.

[You can read here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0425/ch03s06s03.html)